# Is possible to have full guest system under host installed via DebootstrapChroot?

Tags: debian, x11, chroot, lxc, debootstrap

My goal is installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS under Debian 7 wheezy with full GNOME Desktop. I know I can use use tools like VirtualBox etc. but it seems like overhead. To be more precise under this Ubuntu I want to install one application ([nupic](https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Installing-NuPIC-on-Ubuntu) if anyone interested) seems that installing this on Ubuntu is less painless process than installing it on Debian.

)

Four questions:

1. Is this possible using [DebootstrapChroot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot)? If not would it be possible if I do not want to use X server of Ubuntu?
2. Is there some similar technique (e.g. LXC, maybe Docker but AFAIK it is under the hood LXC) for achieving this?
3. Is possible also install DebootstrapChroot from iso image or debootstrap is needed?
4. Does DebootstrapChroot only work for Debian related distros?

Comment: `debootstrap` and `chroot` are separate programs merely used together in this case. Yes, DEB-based distros only, but there are alternatives for other distros, such as RPM-based. Docker provides linux containers, yes, but it doesn't use the LXC backend anymore (it used to do that, though). Usually you'd use a `debootstrap`-like process to install an LXC container anyway. In fact all the templates for Debian and Ubuntu make use of `debootstrap`.

Comment: So DebbotstrapChroot will be fine for me or not? Or how can use to install debootsrap  LXC? Thank you

Comment: yes it will be okay as long as the Debian kernel you're running is sufficiently recent, such that the libc included with the LXC guest you want to install will work with it. Simply using `lxc-create` with the respective Ubuntu template will do the job quite nicely. But to connect to the X app inside you need to set up networking etc.

Comment: I'm counting on with networking setup. SO now we re talking about LXC yes? What about debootstrap and chroot? Should i choose LXC or debootstrap+chroot? Can you point me to some good tutorial? Thank you

Comment: I'm not aware of how you'd be able to share a socket from inside the `chroot`-ed environment available on the host. Perhaps bind-mounting helps. LXC, when installed, will take care of bridging requests to the guest if you use the default config.

Comment: I suppose it should be possible somehow, otherwise it will not make sense ot have machines in containers that are unable to communicate to outside word. the question is if it will met my requirements described in question?